# fresh win10 install, missing driver needed for install

Tags: windows, drivers, installation

New homebuilt machine, installing Windows 10 (for software requirements) after happily running Linux on it for a month with no issues.  Buy license key, download ISO, make bootable USB, boot from it, and the message we are getting is that a driver is needed for the install process that it can't find, and to insert disk with driver.  So, we insert a disk with all of the downloaded (and extracted in the case of zip files) drivers for the system, and it finds quite a few things when prompted, but none are whatever it needs to finish the install.

So... HOW can I determine what piece of hardware it isn't finding support for that is required for install?

I can see the hard drive (it prompts me to format if I try to access it while browsing for drivers), CD drive, USB is working.  Obviously video keyboard and mouse are working.  USB network is supposed to have support built in for the dongle we have.

Ideas? I've not really played with Windows since the Windows NT 4 Workstation days ....

Hardware -

- GIGABYTE GA-AB350-GAMING 3 (rev. 1.0) AM4 AMD B350 SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.1 HDMI ATX AMD Motherboard
- AMD RYZEN 3 1200 4-Core 3.1 GHz (3.4 GHz Turbo) Socket AM4 65W YD1200BBAEBOX Desktop Processor
- Visiontek Radeon 6450 1GB DDR3 (DVI-D, HDMI, VGA), 900371
- 8gb compatible RAM, 1tb SATA hard drive, USB wireless dongle that Win 10 is supposed to have support built-in.

Note that this system Just Works with Linux Mint 18.3, Debian Stretch, etc

When we browse our downloaded and extracted drivers, it does find chipset, USB, even video BUT even after all of those we can't get it to continue on - it still insists on a missing driver.

Screenie of error -

[image: photo of error]

Comment: We need to know about your system in order to help.  Edit your question if you don’t mind.

Comment: Also put a screenshot of the error message. May be it mentions the hardware name /id

Comment: @Ramhound - info added.  still no idea as to where to look to find what it is complaining about missing.

Comment: @GaneshR. if it had mentioned a hardware ID I wouldn't have posted the question :)  As you can see the screenie says it may be related to DVD, USB, or disk drive BUT all are usable to browse through in order to find said driver.

Comment: What mode is your SATA ports currently in?  If you had RAID mode enabled the drivers being requested are likely associated with that setting.

Comment: @Ramhound - no RAIDing going on.  Found a few other posts with exact same error, swapping the USB install drive around didn't help BUT found one post indicating possible bad install media, so I'm re-downloading (over a 1mb/s dsl line :( ).  Unfortunately, MS doesn't publish a hash sum to verify dl integrity....

Comment: @ivanivan - If you use the Media Creation Tool, you don't need to know the hash sum, the tool verifies the download is correct.  They actually do publish the sum, you just have to know where to look, but I strongly suggest using the tool instead of trying to create the bootable media by hand.

Comment: integrate the USB 3.1 and SATA drivers to the boot.wim via DISM

Comment: @magicandre1981 - can't. no windows machines in the house, and at work the windows machines are locked down (and my workstation is Linux there as well).  I'm hoping the first image I downloaded was corrupt...

Comment: @Ramhound - no windows machines available.  Or Macs... well, I have 2 macs, but they both run Linux too... Fortunately MS provides a straight ISO download... hoping first download was corrupt, it does have a different `md5sum` than the one I'm getting now (I download to a VPS, check sum, then download to my local machine over sloooow connection)

Comment: I would agree with your conclusion that you have an incomplete installation image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, not sure but after re-downloading the ISO and putting it on a USB drive (via both "USB Image Writer" - `mint-stick` - and straight up `dd`) it still did not work.  Did some reconfiguration of my workstation to add a DVD burner, burnt a DVD of the ISO I downloaded, and it is cheerfully installing away.

What a PITA.

Thanks for the help and suggestions!